# Logical Operators and their precedence in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, operators, logical-operators

I was recently came across a piece of code

// Program to overcome division by zero

```
int a=0;
int b=100;

int c= a==0 || b/a ;

printf("Hello");
```

//Output : Hello

My theory:
According to the precedence, operator / has higher precedence than ||. So  b/a must get executed first and we should get a run time error.

I assume what is happening though is :

short-circuit operator || , evaluates the LHS a==0, which is true and hence does not execute b/a.

Is my theory wrong?. I am pretty sure this is something very simple that i just can't figure out right now

Comment: Please tell me why write code that you have to scratch your head to figure out what is going on? It is stupid, cannot be maintained and therefore is c**P! Pray tell what is the point of writing such code.

Comment: @EdHeal This is quite common, actually. The only thing bothering me is that `(a==0)` is treated as int 0 instead of boolean false when assigned to `c`, but I believe that's a C thing anyway.

Comment: @EdHeal I haven't written this code, i saw this code in some program that i was going through.

Comment: @GolezTrol `a == 0` evaluates to 1/true. There is an implicit conversion from `bool` to `int`, so `int c = boolean_expression;` is equivalent to `int c = boolean_expression ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: @DanielFischer,thanks- big united fan :).

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that. I was responding on Ed Heals statement about 'stupid, unmaintainable code'. I think the code is quite clear, except I don't like implicit conversions, especially in a strong typed language like C. But I don't think it's really a conversion. In C, booleans seem to be just ints where 0 is false and other values are/evaluate to true. I can't imagine there's actually a conversion going on when you look at the outputted object code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precedence doesn't imply evaluation order, only grouping (parentheses).

There is a sequence point (old parlance) after the evluation of the first operand of the `||`, so the first operand of `||` must be evaluated before the second, regardless of what these operands are. Since in this case the overall result of the expression `a == 0 || b/a` was determined by the first operand, the second isn't evaluated at all.

Comment: +1. This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Awesome piece of information, thanks @GolezTrol and Daniel Fischer . I was assuming it was some simple syntax issue that i was missing.

Comment: There must be something fundamentally wrong, that teachers say when explaining operator precedence, because a long of people come out thinking that it has something to do with order of evaluation. Maybe some kind of organization is needed, to roam the classes of the world finding people who say, "first the highest-precedence operator is evaluated" (or whatever the elementary error is), bundle them into vans and drive them to a secret base for re-education.

Answer (score 3):

The higher precedence of `/` over `||` means that the expression is evaluated as:

```
int c= (a==0) || (b/a) ;
```

And not

```
int c= (a==0 || b)/a ;
```

But still, as the logical evaluation is short-circuited, `b/a` will only be evaluated if `a!=0`.